# What happens if I deliver a bitizen to the interrogation level?

Tags: star-wars-tiny-death-star

If I try to drop off a bitizen at any level they don't want to be at they simply won't get off the elevator. However if I deliver a bitizen to the interrogation level they will always get off... And then vanish shortly after.

[image]

What happens if I deliver a bitizen to the interrogation level?

Will i ever see them again? Do these people DIE?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can deliver a bitizen to any imperial level at any time they are in the elevator. If that imperial level is currently under construction, or it is making an item (filling an order), it will result in the wait time until completion being reduced by 1 minute.

As for the bitizen, the normal thing is the bitizen is gone forever (unless it is a special bitizen such as Luke or Leia or C3PO). This is the same fate as what happens to any bitizen "shopper" or residential visitor to your non-imperial levels.

Answer (score 3):

If you deliver Leia Organa(Rebel) to interrogation you get a scene.

Anyone else, and they merely walk off like any other floor.

If it is a special character they will continue to reappear at random throughout the game. If it is a randomly generated visitor, there is no consequence for delivering them there except the loss of their tip for ferrying them to their floor that they request.

In general, unless you need to shorten the build time or supply time on an imperial floor, there is little reason to deliver anyone there. The exception being when they request to go there, or a special character to unlock a scene.